# Advanced SQL condition based query building

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a complex SQL query based on a condition. If the condition is satisfied, it should run the query with one condition, if not then another condition. How is this possible in SQL?

```
SELECT distinct support_id AS object_id, 2 as app_context_id,
            0 as domain_cdc_id, 'S' as object_type, 
            'NEW' as domain_cdc_status, 1 as attribute_group_num,s
            sysdate as created_on 
FROM fdrdbo.v_facility_support
WHERE support_version_valid_from_dt = to_date('${passedInVar}', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

IF `${passedInVar}` is null, then I want to use the following WHERE condition instead:

```
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN support_version_valid_from_dt AND support_version_valid_to_dt
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: cant. this data is coming from a business datasource and im modifying the query within the application

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, and Postgres are all different dialects.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Postgresql (`to_date` exists in Postgresql)

```
where
    support_version_valid_from_dt = to_date(:passedinvar, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    or
    (
        sysdate between support_version_valid_from_dt and support_version_valid_to_dt 
        and
        :passedinvar is null
    )
```

Notice that I'm assuming you are using a driver to pass the variable and not doing simple string substitution.

`to_date` will return `null` for a `null` argument. In Postgresql a comparison to `null` will return `null`. The second condition will only be checked if the passed variable is null.

Comment: It will be string substitution

Comment: @user836087 It shouldn't be. Very bad habit. Even if you're convinced this particular case is safe, you might get a http://bobby-tables.com/ surprise one day after unrelated code refactoring etc...